# Matomo encountered an error: Call to undefined function Davaxi\Sparkline\mb_strlen() (which lead to: Zend_Session is currently marked as read-only.)

Tags: matomo

I'm getting this error on my Matomo installation:

> Matomo encountered an error: Call to undefined function Davaxi\Sparkline\mb_strlen() (which lead to: Zend_Session is currently marked as read-only.)

This shows up when looking into the reason for dysfunctional images:

[image]

With such URLs:

`/index.php?date=2019-02-05,2019-03-06&forceView=1&viewDataTable=sparkline&module=API&action=get&widget=1&idSite=1&period=day&columns=nb_visits%2Cnb_uniq_visitors&colors=%7B%22backgroundColor%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%2C%22lineColor%22%3A%22%23162c4a%22%2C%22minPointColor%22%3A%22%23ff7f7f%22%2C%22maxPointColor%22%3A%22%2375bf7c%22%2C%22lastPointColor%22%3A%22%2355aaff%22%2C%22fillColor%22%3A%22%23ffffff%22%7D`

Answer (score 1):

The key to the problem is "undefined function … mb_strlen". This means that the PHP mbstring (multibyte string) extension is not installed. On Ubuntu Linux with PHP 7 I used the command:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
```

It then started working fine immediately.

On different systems there’ll be different commands required. The PHP manual section on the [multibyte string extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) might be of some help.